# Adding Cells to UITableView from array

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, nsarray

I pass an array called `userArray` which stores another array with strings. This is what I have so far but I know it's wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Set Up Cell
    DataSingleton *sharedData = [DataSingleton sharedData];

    for (NSArray *array in sharedData.usersArray){
        cell.primaryLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:1];
        cell.secondaryLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:2];
        cell.profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"111-user.png"];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your return supposed to be inside the for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a `UITableViewDataSource` method, and it asks the data for single cell only. So, you have to remove a loop, and set up a single cell at once, using `indexPath.row` as an array index in your `DataSingleton`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Set Up Cell
    DataSingleton *sharedData = [DataSingleton sharedData];

    NSArray *array = [sharedData.usersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.primaryLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:1];
    cell.secondaryLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:2];
    cell.profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"111-user.png"];
    return cell;   
}
```

Also, you should implement `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to return `[[[DataSingleton sharedData] usersArray] count]`

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by returning the count? EDIT: NVM I SEE WHAT YOU MEAN

Comment: Did you mean:  'return [[[DataSingleton sharedData] usersArray] count];' ? either way I'm getting a null value

Comment: Ok, I realized I was switching views before it had a chance to write to my singleton but your inital post worked. Thank you very much.